# How to divide the data in blocks and calculate mean-square displacement?

Tags: python, numpy, statistics, physics, numba

I want to calculate the mean-square displacement using the blocking scheme mentioned here [blocking scheme for correlations](http://pdebuyl.be/blog/2016/correlators.html). The main idea is to store the data in blocks of certain length as mentioned in the link. I have the data in shape (10, 11214,3), there are 10 frames containing 11214 data points in 3-dimension. So now I want to store every two frames in a block and then use their running average to calculate the mean-square displacement. Can anyone know how to implement this method?

Here is data [file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/np4zddobttbtjq0/com?dl=0) and here is the code that I'm using for calculating normal msd

```py
import numpy as np
import numba as nb

@nb.njit
def get_msd_traj_nb1(p):
    result = np.zeros_like(p)
    deltastop = p.shape[1]
    for traj in range(p.shape[0]):
        for dim in range(p.shape[2]):
            for delta in range(1, deltastop):
                thisresult = 0
                for i in range(delta, deltastop):
                    thisresult += (p[traj,i,dim] - p[traj,i-delta,dim])**2
                    result[traj,delta,dim] = thisresult / (deltastop-delta)
    return result

m = get_msd_traj_nb1(dataset)
print(m.shape)
```

Comment: Can you provide an example for input and expected output and explain the inner steps?

Comment: Is this line of the code snippet indented one level too far: `result[traj,delta,dim] = thisresult / (deltastop-delta)`?

Comment: I guess if you could solve this for toy data of shape (3, 8, 2) or something then it would scale up easily.  As @Hakan suggested, sample input and output would be useful.